# Globally declare and reuse code in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I want to declare my dockerfile node globally and use it for my stages.
This is my jenkinsfile now:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Prepare Build') {
            agent {
                dockerfile {
                    label agentLabel
                    args "-u root:root -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock "
                    filename 'Dockerfile'
                }
            }
            steps {}
        }
        stage('Build & Unit Test') {
            agent {
                dockerfile {
                    label agentLabel
                    args "-u root:root -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock "
                    filename 'Dockerfile'
                }
            }
            steps {}
        }
        stage('Integration tests') {
            agent {
                dockerfile {
                    label agentLabel
                    args "-u root:root -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock "
                    filename 'Dockerfile'
                }
            }
            when {
                not {
                    branch releaseCandidateBranch
                }
            }
            steps {}
        }
        stage('Functional tests') {
            agent {
                dockerfile {
                    label agentLabel
                    args "-u root:root -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock "
                    filename 'Dockerfile'
                }
            }
            steps {}
        }
        stage('Update Version') {
            agent {
                dockerfile {
                    label agentLabel
                    args "-u root:root -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock "
                    filename 'Dockerfile'
                }
            }
            steps {}
        }
        stage('Cleanup') {
            agent {
                dockerfile {
                    label agentLabel
                    args "-u root:root -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock "
                    filename 'Dockerfile'
                }
            }
            steps {
                sh "chmod -R 777 ."
                deleteDir()
            }
        }

        stage('On a linux machine') {
            agent {
                label 'linux machine'
            }
            stages {
                stage('Publish Package') {
                    environment {
                        JAVA_HOME = '/opt/bb/libexec/openjdk-java11-linux-x86-64'
                    }
                    steps {}
                }
            }
            post {
                cleanup {
                    deleteDir()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to reuse the dockerfile code block so that it looks something like this:

```
def dockerAgent = dockerfile {
                  label agentLabel
                  args "-u root:root -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock "
                  filename 'Dockerfile'
              }
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Prepare Build') {
            agent = dockerAgent
            steps {}
        }
        stage('Build & Unit Test') {
            agent = dockerAgent
            steps {}
        }

        ...

        stage('On a linux machine') {
            agent {
                label 'linux machine'
            }
            stages {
                stage('Publish Package') {
                    environment {
                        JAVA_HOME = '/opt/bb/libexec/openjdk-java11-linux-x86-64'
                    }
                    steps {}
                }
            }
            post {
                cleanup {
                    deleteDir()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

It's similar to question: [Globally declare and reuse node in Jenkinsfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61240472/globally-declare-and-reuse-node-in-jenkinsfile), but I don't want to add all the stages under a single stage. This makes it hard to restart the build from a particular stage if it fails.

Comment: From what I understand Shared libraries might be a good candidate to your resolution even if it seems overkill